# Excel PowerQuery: How to unpivot or transpose a huge table into a readable format for analysis

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have this table that looks similar to this:
[image]

And I want to transform it so that it looks like this:

[image]

The idea is to unpivot( or transpose) the table so that it can be feed into other BI tools, and be readable for analysis.

I have around 20 tables like this with 100+ cols, so of course to do it manually is nearly impossible.

How do I get this done with PowerQuery? I have tried using unpivot feature, but I am stuck as it displayed NYC1, NYC2, etc. VBA, macros don't work also. Any other suggestions are appreciated, but I am at my wits end now. Help!

Comment: What VBA did you try?

Comment: I tried to recreate a macro and tweak it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203225/excel-table-breakdown-to-separate-sheets but decided that using PowerQuery is a better approach here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before loading into PowerQuery, concatenate the headers to the empty row after [Programe Name] using a delimiter (space). You can use the TEXTJOIN function to do this if you use office365. The result looks something like this (I did not copy all your data):

[image]

Import this range into PowerQuery and perform the following steps (Do not check the `my table has headers` checkbox)

1. Remove top 2 rows (Home tab > Remove Rows)
2. Use first row as headers (Home tab > Use First Row as Headers)
3. Select the first column
4. Unpivot other columns (dropdown menu unpivot columns on Transform Tab)
5. Split the [Attribute] column by delimiter (space) (Home tab > Split Column)
6. Change column names
7. Move City column to the left (rightclick column > move > left)

The script looks like this:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="table"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type any}, {"Column3", type any}, {"Column4", type any}, {"Column5", type any}, {"Column6", type any}, {"Column7", type any}, {"Column8", type any}, {"Column9", type any}}),
    #"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(#"Changed Type",2),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Removed Top Rows", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Program Name", type text}, {"NY Budget", Int64.Type}, {"NY Revenue", Int64.Type}, {"NY Cost", Int64.Type}, {"NY Margin", Int64.Type}, {"LA Budget", Int64.Type}, {"LA Revenue", Int64.Type}, {"LA Cost", Int64.Type}, {"LA Margin", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type1", {"Program Name"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Attribute", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Attribute.1", "Attribute.2"}),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Attribute.1", type text}, {"Attribute.2", type text}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type2",{{"Attribute.1", "City"}, {"Attribute.2", "Description"}}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Renamed Columns",{"City", "Program Name", "Description", "Value"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

And this is the result (in the Power Query Editor)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here's a pretty generic depivot approach which handles multiple row/column headers.

Select a cell in the source table before running (note - this uses `CurrentRegion` so will fail if your table has completely blank rows or columns).

```
Sub UnpivotIt()

    Dim numRowHeaders As Long, numColHeaders As Long
    Dim numRows As Long, numCols As Long, rng As Range
    Dim rngOut As Range, r As Long, c As Long, i As Long, n As Long
    Dim arrIn, arrOut, outRow As Long

    arrIn = Selection.CurrentRegion.Value

    numRowHeaders = Application.InputBox("How many header rows?", Type:=1)
    numColHeaders = Application.InputBox("How many header columns?", Type:=1)
    Set rngOut = Application.InputBox("Select output (top-left cell)", Type:=8)

    Set rngOut = rngOut.Cells(1) 'in case >1 cells selected

    numRows = UBound(arrIn, 1)
    numCols = UBound(arrIn, 2)

    ReDim arrOut(1 To ((numRows - numRowHeaders) * (numCols - numColHeaders)), _
                 1 To (numRowHeaders + numColHeaders + 1))

    outRow = 0
    For r = (numRowHeaders + 1) To numRows
    For c = (numColHeaders + 1) To numCols
        'only copy if there's a value
        If Len(arrIn(r, c)) > 0 Then
            outRow = outRow + 1
            i = 1
            For n = 1 To numColHeaders 'copy column headers
                arrOut(outRow, i) = arrIn(r, n)
                i = i + 1
            Next n
            For n = 1 To numRowHeaders '...row headers
                arrOut(outRow, i) = arrIn(n, c)
                i = i + 1
            Next n
            arrOut(outRow, i) = arrIn(r, c) '...and the value
        End If
    Next c
    Next r

    rngOut.Resize(outRow, UBound(arrOut, 2)).Value = arrOut

End Sub
```