# Multi Column to Fixed Column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for help with converting 14 Columns into 4 Columns
At present, I've come across several example but none have met my needs.
Below are the screen shots that shows before and after.

thank you in advance

[image: 14 Columns]

[image: 4 Columns - Resource, Project Name, Date, Quantity]

Code example for Multiple to single column which doesn't meet the specs

```
Sub MultipleColumns2SingleColumn()
 Const shName1 As String = "Sheet1"       'Change sheet name here
 Const shName2 As String = "Sheet2"
 Dim arr, arrNames
 With Worksheets(shName1)
    arrNames = .Range("F1", .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
    For i = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        arr = .Cells(i, 1).Resize(, 4)
        With Worksheets(shName2)
            With .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
                .Offset(1).Resize(UBound(arrNames, 2), 4) = arr
                .Offset(1, 5).Resize(UBound(arrNames, 2)) = Application.Transpose(arrNames)
            End With
        End With
    Next
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like you could just use a pivot table for that... no code needed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218565/excel-powerquery-how-to-unpivot-or-transpose-a-huge-table-into-a-readable-forma/53220283#53220283  Search here for "depivot" or "unpivot"

Comment: @braX it's the reverse. He starts from pivot table like data and would like to get data in four columns.