# Transposing dummy variables

Tags: excel, vba, transpose

I would like to transform the structure of an excel file so that I can import it into a system which needs it to be structured in a given way.

Here is a small extraction of the excel file. There is a combination of categorical variables such as *Line of business* and four dummy variables indicating which data categories are used in a given process - such as *Customer*.

```
| Process name | Line of business | Customer | Potential customer | Employee | Vendor |
|--------------|------------------|----------|--------------------|----------|--------|
| Ad campaign  | Marketing        | x        | x                  |          | x      |
| Payroll      | HR               |          |                    | x        | x      |
```

**What I want** is to change the structure so that a new row is created for each variation of the dummy variables, and with a *Data category* column that applies/transposes the relevant data category name. The desired output would look like this:

```
| Process name | Line of business | Data category      |
|--------------|------------------|--------------------|
| Ad campaign  | Marketing        | Customer           |
| Ad campaign  | Marketing        | Potential customer |
| Ad campaign  | Marketing        | Vendor             |
| Payroll      | HR               | Employee           |
| Payroll      | HR               | Vendor             |
```

**What I have tried** is making a COUNTIF statement that counts the number of "x" per row. I have then used a vba script that creates a new line with the process name for each variation of data categories.
Here is the code and the letters in the script refers to the columns in excel, so A is the *Process name* column and G is the *COUNTIF* column and it creates the n number of rows I need.

```
Sub KopyKat()
   Dim N As Long, i As Long, K As Long
   Dim v As String, kk As Long, m As Long
   N = Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
   K = 1

   For i = 2 To N
      kk = Cells(i, "G").Value
      v = Cells(i, "A").Value
      For m = 1 To kk
         Cells(K + 1, "H") = v
         K = K + 1
      Next m
   Next i
End Sub
```

So that it goes from this:

```
| Process name | Line of business | Customer | Potential customer | Employee | Vendor | COUNTIF |
|--------------|------------------|----------|--------------------|----------|--------|---------|
| Ad campaign  | Marketing        | x        | x                  |          | x      | 3       |
| Payroll      | HR               |          |                    | x        | x      | 2       |
```

To this:

```
| Process name | Line of business | Customer | Potential customer | Employee | Vendor | COUNTIF | Process name_2 |
|--------------|------------------|----------|--------------------|----------|--------|---------|----------------|
| Ad campaign  | Marketing        | x        | x                  |          | x      | 3       | Ad campaign    |
| Payroll      | HR               |          |                    | x        | x      | 2       | Ad campaign    |
|              |                  |          |                    |          |        |         | Ad campaign    |
|              |                  |          |                    |          |        |         | Payroll        |
|              |                  |          |                    |          |        |         | Payroll        |
```

This is where my limited vba knowledge have taken me. I would like to change the code so that I get my desired output. 

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218565/excel-powerquery-how-to-unpivot-or-transpose-a-huge-table-into-a-readable-forma/53220283#53220283

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done simply with Power Query (available in Excel 2010+)
All steps can be done from the UI, but the M-code is below

**Edit:**  Added step to rename **Attribute** column

- Get data from table/range
- Select the first two columns, then `Unpivot Other Columns`
- Filter the **Value** column to show only the x's
- Delete the **Value** column
- Rename **Attribute** column -->  **`Data Category`**

#### M-Code

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Process name", type text}, {"Line of business", type text}, {"Customer", type text}, {"Potential customer", type text}, {"Employee", type text}, {"Vendor", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Process name", "Line of business"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", each ([Value] = "x")),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Value"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Attribute", "Data Category"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I recommend Power Query for data this kind of data manipulation.

Secondly, if you must do it this way, I think putting your data in an actual Excel table is much better for organizing your data and writing your code.

Anyways, below you can find my solution. Based on how many input columns you have, you can adjust the inner loop.

Note: looping over cells one by one is not the most efficient way. If the data size is big, reading the values into an array, and changing them in memory will increase the calculation speed 100+ times. If you can provide more information about the data size, I can update my answer accordingly.

```
Option Explicit

Sub KopyKat()
    Dim totalRow As Long
    totalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'Result and data input sheets are specified here.
    Dim wsInput As Worksheet:     Set wsInput = Worksheets("Sheet5")
    Dim wsOutput As Worksheet:     Set wsOutput = Worksheets("Sheet6")

    Dim i As Long 'Row
    Dim j As Long 'Column
    Dim counter As Long:    counter = 0

   For i = 2 To totalRow
      For j = 3 To 6 'Column numbers are hardcoded for the sake of the example

      'Assumption is that value "x" is the only way to specify
        If wsInput.Cells(i, j).Value = "x" Then
            With wsOutput
                .Cells(counter + 2, 1) = wsInput.Cells(i, 1).Value 'Process Name
                .Cells(counter + 2, 2) = wsInput.Cells(i, 2).Value 'Line of Business
                .Cells(counter + 2, 3) = wsInput.Cells(1, j).Value 'Data Category
            End With
          counter = counter + 1
        End If

      Next j
   Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Nuri! As you pointed out, doing this in Power Query was the most effective for me given the large size of the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Check this code and customize it according to your needs:

Based on this data layout:

[image]

```
Sub Transpose()

    Dim evalSheet As Worksheet
    Dim evalRange As Range
    Dim headerRange As Range
    Dim evalCell As Range
    Dim destCell As Range

    Dim sheetName As String
    Dim sourceRangeAddress As String
    Dim headerRangeAddress As String
    Dim destinationCellAddress As String

    Dim rowCounter As Long

    ' Customize to fit your needs
    sheetName = "Sheet1"
    sourceRangeAddress = "A2:F3"
    headerRangeAddress = "A1:F1"
    destinationCellAddress = "I2"

    Set evalSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName )

    ' Get the range
    Set evalRange = evalSheet.Range(sourceRangeAddress)

    Set headerRange = evalSheet.Range(headerRangeAddress)

    Set destCell = evalSheet.Range(destinationCellAddress)

    ' Loop through each cell in the first column
    For Each evalCell In evalRange.Columns(1).Cells

        ' Evaluate the four columns (columnOffset means how many columns to the right)
        If Trim(evalCell.Offset(columnOffset:=2).Value) = "x" Then
            destCell.Offset(rowOffset:=rowCounter, columnOffset:=0).Value = Trim(evalCell.Offset(columnOffset:=0).Value)
            destCell.Offset(rowOffset:=rowCounter, columnOffset:=1).Value = Trim(evalCell.Offset(columnOffset:=1).Value)
            ' Header range cells (3) means the third cell in the range - different than offset
            destCell.Offset(rowOffset:=rowCounter, columnOffset:=2).Value = Trim(headerRange.Cells(3).Value)

            rowCounter = rowCounter + 1

        End If

        If Trim(evalCell.Offset(columnOffset:=3).Value) = "x" Then
            destCell.Offset(rowOffset:=rowCounter, columnOffset:=0).Value = Trim(evalCell.Offset(columnOffset:=0).Value)
            destCell.Offset(rowOffset:=rowCounter, columnOffset:=1).Value = Trim(evalCell.Offset(columnOffset:=1).Value)
            destCell.Offset(rowOffset:=rowCounter, columnOffset:=2).Value = Trim(headerRange.Cells(4).Value)

            rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
        End If
        If Trim(evalCell.Offset(columnOffset:=4).Value) = "x" Then
            destCell.Offset(rowOffset:=rowCounter, columnOffset:=0).Value = Trim(evalCell.Offset(columnOffset:=0).Value)
            destCell.Offset(rowOffset:=rowCounter, columnOffset:=1).Value = Trim(evalCell.Offset(columnOffset:=1).Value)
            destCell.Offset(rowOffset:=rowCounter, columnOffset:=2).Value = Trim(headerRange.Cells(5).Value)

            rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
        End If
        If Trim(evalCell.Offset(columnOffset:=5).Value) = "x" Then
            destCell.Offset(rowOffset:=rowCounter, columnOffset:=0).Value = Trim(evalCell.Offset(columnOffset:=0).Value)
            destCell.Offset(rowOffset:=rowCounter, columnOffset:=1).Value = Trim(evalCell.Offset(columnOffset:=1).Value)
            destCell.Offset(rowOffset:=rowCounter, columnOffset:=2).Value = Trim(headerRange.Cells(6).Value)

            rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
        End If
    Next evalCell

End Sub
```

Remember to mark the answer if this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot Ricardo! This works! As I found out through Ron's answer, doing this in PowerQuery was the most efficient and most intuitive for someone with no vba coding experience.

Comment: Awesome! As you requested in your Question, I provided the VBA solution. PowerQuery is a great alternative!