# Adding a multi-dimensional item into an array, then retrieving all of the items at once

Tags: arrays, .net, excel, vba

So I'm working on learning arrays in VBA.

VBA does not treat arrays very nicely, and I found a .net implementation in VBA that seems to work better/cleaner. Great, let's use that!

So I start by making my sub, dimming the array, and setting it:

```
Sub ArrayTest()
Dim StorageArray as Variant

Set StorageArray = CreateObject("System.Collection.Arraylist")
```

Hurray, working array!
Let's add items to it.

```
StorageArray.Add "Peter"

For i = 1 to 4
    StorageArray.Add i
Next i
```

Works great!

Let's get items out of it.

```
For each Name in StorageArray
    debug.print Name
Next
end sub
```

Everything's rosy up until here. Now I want to go a bit more advanced: I want to add multi-dimensional objects to the array, and I want to dumb the ENTIRE array all at once into Excel. This is where it breaks down.

`StorageArray.Add "Peter", "Paul"` yells at me for a non-specified syntax error. `StorageArray.Add ("Peter", "Paul")` continues to yell at me.

`ShTest.Range("A1").value2 = StorageArray` also yells at me. "Missing paramater does not have a default value. Paramater name: Parameters" is the error given.

I know at one point I could dump an entire array out into Excel like that, but I was building off of someone elses code that I no longer have access to, so I can't figure out what the difference is.

I'm willing to look into other array methods, but the reason I'm looking into this in the first place is I have a large (~70k lines) file that needs a table unpivoted. PowerQuery is THE textbook tool for doing this, however, I don't have access to it. Apparently SQL could also help, but my SQL knowledge isn't strong enough. A double loop works, but it takes literal hours to process, and I know it can be done in minutes. I suspected that most of the time is taken up by writing the data one line at a time to the results sheet, so I'm looking into arrays to speed things up massively.

Comment: https://www.tachytelic.net/2019/09/vba-add-item-array/ is what I'm using as a reference - short version, apparently it re-calculates each time you add an item

Comment: What is the size in megabytes of the 70k line file. Is it plain text or some other format that you want to import into a Results sheet in a Excel workbook ?

Comment: I guess a typical unpivot task with 70k rows isn't a problem to be implemented with conventional VBA arrays. Could you please add some more info on your file that needs a table unpivoted?

Comment: They put the dates as column headers - so Jan 1st, Jan 2nd, etc. I'm trying to convert it into a more traditional look (with a bit of filtering applied for items I don't want, simple If stuff)

Comment: You'd be better off finding out how arrays work in VBA (it's not that complex!) - if you want to implement an unpivot then that's likely the best way to go (once you figure out your unpivot logic).  Trying to find out how ArrayList can help via trial and error isn't going to be a very productive path to take, and if you want to put the final result onto a worksheet in a single operation then likely you'd need to do that via a regular VBA array anyway.

Comment: @TimWilliams: Yeah, I'm currently having steam coming out of my ears as I try to learn regular arrays - trying to figure out how to redim preserve and add one line, then insert content into that new line right now

Comment: Remember you don't need to build it up by adding a new "line" in a loop - just start off by making it as large as you think it will need to be (or larger) then you can cut it down in one step when you're done.  Just need to keep track of the last-populated "row" number as you're filling it.  Eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218565/excel-powerquery-how-to-unpivot-or-transpose-a-huge-table-into-a-readable-forma/53220283#53220283

Comment: @TimWilliams: That's actually the exact problem I was working on when I popped over, and yes, that did just make a lightbulb go off- thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Excel VBA treats the arrays in a peculiar way, but it has something suitable only to Excel ranges, which I think is good to be known and used. Also, a collection is not suitable for your purpose, I think.

So, if you declare the arrays in the way you did, so created array are 0 based type and it is not complicated to use multi-dimensional ones, but let us say more complicated...

Besides this way of declaring, it is an Excel specific one working like that:

```
Private Sub testArrays()
  Dim arrTest As Variant, rng As Range, sh As Worksheet
   Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your sheet
   Set rng = sh.Range("A2:K1000")
     arrTest = rng.Value
     Debug.Print UBound(arrTest, 1), UBound(arrTest, 2)
     'UBound(arrTest, 1) = array rows and UBound(arrTest, 2) = array columns
End Sub
```

The resulted array is a multi-dimensional 1 based type.
You can speed up your application working only in memory using such a type. You can also mix things loading any arrays type in a loop iterating between this one elements...
For pasting at once use the next code:

```
Dim shNew As Worksheet
    Set shNew = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("2")
    shNew.Range("A2:K1000").Value = arrTest
```

You only must take care of pasting the array in a range having the same rows and colums. Of course, if you need all data from the array...

Answer (score 1):

You need a combination of Collections and Arrays.

```
Sub ArrayDemo()
    ' We could equally use Dim myArray(1 to 5) as variant
    Dim myArrays As Collection
    Set myArrays = New Collection
    myArrays.Add Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 13, 6, 7, 8)

    Dim myVar As Variant
    myVar = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z20").Value
    myArrays.Add myVar
    myArrays.Add Split("This is a sentence that is split into an array", " ")

    myArrays.Add Array(1, "Hello World", myArrays.Item(1), 3.142, New Collection)
    Debug.Print myArrays.Item(1)(4)
    Debug.Print myArrays.Item(2)(4, 6)
    Debug.Print myArrays.Item(3)(3)

End Sub
```

In the example above I've used a Collection to hold my arrays but you could also use an array of variants.

Comment: That looks pretty workable! The only question I have, how do I dump all of the data out at once? Do I need to cycle through every single item?

Comment: You can put an array back into excel by assigning the array to a worksheet range.  Lots of example on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Right, but your example has a collection, and I'm trying to work out how to dump the data out of that collection into Excel in one shot, without looping through and putting in numbers one at a time

Comment: @Selkie: Look to my answer, please, and see how to do what you request...

Comment: VBA doesn't support putting a collection into excel.  You have to use an array..  The array can only contain items that excel understands so you can't have an array item that is an object.