# How to convert matrix to row-column pair in MS excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have one excel sheet have matrix that show sales information of items in each branch like this image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izniZ.png)

I want to create another sheet in the same file to show the data in three columns like (Branch/Item/Value) as this image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odmBm.png)

Is there any method in Excel can do this job?

I tried to do this manually but I have big data sheet that contains 1200 branch and 64 items. Also I tried to do the =INDEX function but it seems not doing what I'm looking for.

Comment: Refer this link. [Excel PowerQuery: How to unpivot or transpose a huge table into a readable format for analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218565/excel-powerquery-how-to-unpivot-or-transpose-a-huge-table-into-a-readable-forma)

Comment: Load data into PQ, select 'Branch', then click 'Unpivot Other Columns'. Done.