# How to (transpose?) this dataset in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: excel, dataset, transpose

I have two datasets containing data on the number of passages of bicycles at certain bike meters in Montreal.  One dataset is from 2023 and is in the format that I want, but I've found the 2022 data is set up differently and I want to change it into the same format as the 2023 data.  The 2022 data is in the first picture below, and the 2023 is the second.

[2022](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVhaL.png)

[2023](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AULo1.png)

My first idea was to use the transpose function in excel, but I've realized that this would not work because of the ordering of the datetime column.

Comment: Power Query simply. Research there are available solutions here already. Here: **[Unpivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218565/excel-powerquery-how-to-unpivot-or-transpose-a-huge-table-into-a-readable-forma)**

Comment: Or, you can also refer the `MS` Documentation: **[Unpivot-Other-Columns](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unpivot-columns-power-query-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098#:~:text=Here%20is%20the%20sample%20data%20used%20in%20this,Country.%20...%203%20Select%20Transform%20%3E%20Unpivot%20Columns.)**